# Encryption in Wireshark (HTTP, AES, JSON)

Tags: http, encryption, aes, wireshark

I got a HTTP-Post in Wireshark with a encrypted payload. 
Where can I add the Key for decrypting the content?
The Content should be JSON and the encryption is AES 128 bit. I got the Key in HEX.

There was no success using several online decryption tools.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark accepts keys in PEM format. They usually look like this:

```
    -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
Mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

To enter the key in Wireshark, you need to go to Edit-> Preferences -> Protocols -> SSL

Note that the ability of any tool to decipher the encrypted stream depends on the key-exchange mechanism. If the client and server use, for example, a variation of the [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) algorithm for key exchange, it would be impossible to decrypt the stream.